# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, codeblocks

I'm getting this annoying error when compiling a C++ program. I looked it up and didn't find any answer. It's strange because my code is really basic and shouldn't cause any problems at all but yet it does.. I'm using Ubuntu and CODEBLOCKS IDE for the job. Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct database
{
string number;
string spec_number;
char group;
float grade;
string name;
string family_name;
};

void FillDatabase(database student[], short N,short &i);
void SplitDatabase(database student[], short N,short i);




int main()
{
short number_of_students,iteration=0;

//ПРОВЕРКА:
cout << "Za kolko studenta shte vyvejdate? ";
cin >> number_of_students;
cin.ignore();

database student[number_of_students];

FillDatabase(student,number_of_students,iteration);



//МЕНЮ ЗА ИЗБОР
SplitDatabase(student, number_of_students,iteration);


return 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void FillDatabase(database student[], short N,short &i)
{
for(i=0;i < N;i++)
{
//ДОПЪЛНИТЕЛНИ ПРОВЕРКИ ЗА ВАЛИДНОСТ:
cout << endl << endl << "VIE VYVEJDATE ZA STUDENT NOMER " << i+1 << "." << endl;
cout << endl << "Vyvedete fakulteten nomer na studenta...";
cin >> student[i].number;
cout << endl << "Vyvedete kod na specialnostta 52(E) ili 61(AIUT)...";
cin >> student[i].spec_number;
cout << endl << "Vyvedete grupa na studenta...";
cin >> student[i].group;
cout << endl << "Vyvedete sreden uspeh ot semestyra...";
cin >> student[i].grade;
cout << endl << "Vyvedete ime na studenta...";
cin >> student[i].name;
cout << endl << "Vyvedete familiya na studenta...";
cin >> student[i].family_name;
cin.ignore();
}

}

void SplitDatabase(database student[], short N,short i)
{
short count_of_E(0);
for(i=0;i < N;i++)if(student[i].spec_number=="52")count_of_E++;

database E_student[count_of_E];
database AIUT_student[N-count_of_E];

for(i=0;i < N;i++)
{
if(student[i].spec_number=="52")
{
E_student[i].number = student[i].number;
E_student[i].spec_number = student[i].spec_number;
E_student[i].group = student[i].group;
E_student[i].grade = student[i].grade;
E_student[i].name = student[i].name;
E_student[i].family_name = student[i].family_name;
}
else
{
AIUT_student[i].number = student[i].number;
AIUT_student[i].spec_number = student[i].spec_number;
AIUT_student[i].group = student[i].group;
AIUT_student[i].grade = student[i].grade;
AIUT_student[i].name = student[i].name;
AIUT_student[i].family_name = student[i].family_name;
}

}

cout << endl << endl << endl << left << "E" << setw(50) << right << "AIUT" << endl << endl;

for(i=0;i < N;i++)
{
cout << left << E_student[i].name << endl;
cout << left << E_student[i].family_name << endl;
cout << left << E_student[i].number << endl;
cout << left << E_student[i].group << endl;
cout << left << E_student[i].grade << endl << endl;

cout << setw(50) << right << AIUT_student[i].name << endl;
cout << setw(50) << right << AIUT_student[i].family_name << endl;
cout << setw(50) << right << AIUT_student[i].number << endl;
cout << setw(50) << right << AIUT_student[i].group << endl;
cout << setw(50) << right << AIUT_student[i].grade << endl;
}

}

/*
string number;
string spec_number;
char group;
float grade;
string name;
string family_name;



61462166 52 2 5.50
*/
```

I hope that someone lends me a hand here, I'm frustrated....

Comment: Where does it crash? Remove code until it doesn't crash anymore. At this stage, the last bit of code you removed is likely to be the cause for the crash. Then please post the result of your troubleshooting (see also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Do you actually have trouble compiling the code (as your question seems to say) or are you getting a SegFault when you run the compiled executable? If the former, is the compiler getting a SegFault?

Comment: FYI: `database student[number_of_students];` is non-standard C++ when `number_of_students` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Whoever voted to close: the code causing the problem *is* posted in the question. It's not well hidden.

Comment: By the way, "really basic" code doesn't preclude seg faults. Here's a one-liner to compile and run a five character C program that seg faults: `echo "main;" > /tmp/seg.c; gcc /tmp/seg.c -o /tmp/seg; /tmp/seg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (when *running*, not *compiling*) is in lines like these:

```
E_student[i].number = student[i].number;
E_student[i].spec_number = student[i].spec_number;

//...

AIUT_student[i].number = student[i].number;
AIUT_student[i].spec_number = student[i].spec_number;
```

You're looping over `student` from `0..N-1` -- however `E_student` and `AIUT_student` are smaller than `N`. If `N == 4`, and `E_student` and `AIUT_student` are both of size `2`, the last time through the loop you're assigning to `AIUT_student[3]` or `E_student[3]` -- past the end of the respective arrays.

You need to keep separate indices for each array:

```
int ei = 0, ai = 0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  if (student[i].spec_number == "52")
  {
    E_student[ei].number = student[i].number;
    E_student[ei].spec_number = student[i].spec_number;
    E_student[ei].group = student[i].group;
    E_student[ei].grade = student[i].grade;
    E_student[ei].name = student[i].name;
    E_student[ei].family_name = student[i].family_name;
    ++ei;
  }
  else
  {
    AIUT_student[ai].number = student[i].number;
    AIUT_student[ai].spec_number = student[i].spec_number;
    AIUT_student[ai].group = student[i].group;
    AIUT_student[ai].grade = student[i].grade;
    AIUT_student[ai].name = student[i].name;
    AIUT_student[ai].family_name = student[i].family_name;
    ++ai;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not it runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you adress the both partial arrays AIUT_student and E_student with the index of the whole student array. this will result in an access violation latest at N/2+1